# copy constructor parameters

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

In a copy constructor why do arguments need to have default values associated with them?
What happens if there are no default values associated with them and more than one argument is provided in the constructor?

For example:

```
X(const X& copy_from_me, int = 10);
```

has a default value for the int, but this:

```
X(const X& copy_from_me, int);
```

does not.  What happens in this second case?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor

Comment: X(const X& copy_from_me, int = 10);                                  what if i write X(const X& copy_from_me, int);

Comment: +1 for the interesting question, you should put a little more effort into presentation next time around though :)

Comment: That second parameter has absolutely nothing to do with copy constructors.

Answer (score 11):

A copy constructor always takes one parameter, reference to the type for which it belongs, there *maybe* other parameters but they *must* have default values.

An copy constructor is called as an copying function and the purpose of the copy constructor is to create an object of a type by using an object of the same type as basis for creation of the new type.

The Standard specify's that the copy constructor be of the type:

```
T(const &T obj);
```

This basically allows creation of temporary objects during calling functions by value or returning objects of the type by value.
This syntax facilitates creation of an new object as:

```
T obj1(obj2);      <--------- Direct Initialization
T obj1 = obj2;     <--------- Copy Initialization
```

If the additional arguments being passed to the copy constructor would not be mandated to have default values then the construction of objects using the above syntax would not be possible.
Hence the strict condition,
there *maybe* other parameters to a copy constructor but they *must* have default values.

Answer (score 10):

When a copy constructor is invoked, the only thing that's guaranteed to be available is a reference to an instance of the same class. If the copy constructor takes arguments beyond this required reference, those arguments must have default values.

Let's say we have a constructor with the following signature:

```
 X(const X&, int);
```

This cannot be used as a copy constructor because of the second argument. For example:

```
 X x1;
 X x2(x1);
```

How would the compiler use the above constructor for `x2`? It can't.

On the other hand, the following *can* be used as a copy constructor:

```
 X(const X&, int = 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

A copy constructor has one parameter that is a reference to the type that is copied.

It *can* have additional parameters, *if* these have default values. If they don't have  default values, it just isn't a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

A copy constructor has to be callable with just an object of the type to be copied:

```
Thing t1;     // default constructor
Thing t2(t1); // copy constructor
```

If there are extra arguments without default values, then the constructor can't be called like that, so it isn't a copy constructor.