# Can we initialize object with double quotation

Tags: c++

Is it possible to do something like

```
Class obj="";
```

Can use "" to initialize an object? I saw this in an interview, and the interviewer mentioned it is valid.

Update:
Thanks for the answers here. For the benefit of future readers, I did some search, this is called **copy constructor**. Some links like
[copy constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066052/copy-constructor-parameters)
could be useful.

Comment: If "Class" is some C++ class, whether or not this is valid C++ depends on the class's constructor. But, this can certainly be valid C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik It is possible to know what kind of constructor allow this?

Comment: @william007 Such as `Class` has a constructor taking `const char*` as parameter.

Comment: Or a `std::string`.

Comment: Please don't answer in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it really is valid. Here is an example code where it works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Class {
private:
    string data;
public:
    Class (const char* foo) {
        data = foo;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Class foo="bar";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In such a case, why we use Class foo=new Class("bar"); appear to have compilation error?

Comment: @william007 It's because "new Class(...)" returns a pointer, so it should be Class *foo = new Class("bar"). Also, if you didn't want a pointer, it should be Class foo = Class("bar") or Class foo("bar") or Class foo="bar". Either one of these works.

Comment: Thanks Andros, can the format `Class foo="bar"` support >=2 constructor arguments?

Comment: @william007 Surely not. And if it did, it would look ugly (at least to me), so I'd stick to the brackets.

Comment: @william007 It looks like you should start [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).